# How to append data from two table into one table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following

```
Table1

col1   col2
------------
 1      A 
 2      B
 3      C
 4      D


Table2

col1   col2
------------
 5      E 
 6      F
 7      G
 8      H
```

And I want the result like this

```
col1   col2
------------
 1      A 
 2      B
 3      C
 4      D
 5      E 
 6      F
 7      G
 8      H
```

How to do it in MS SQL Server?

Please help me..

I search the Join, Inner Join and other but they are just making 4 colums.

How to do in the way that i want..

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms180026.aspx) the two tables together. Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table2
```

If you want to include any rows that are duplicate, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you so much you just save my head cracking problem

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Select * From Table1
Union ALL
Select * From Table2
```